# How do you execute cleanup code on shutdown in Resin?

Tags: servlets, handler, shutdown, resin, caucho

Is there a way to register a function in Resin so that it runs whenever Resin is shut down? I know you can init servlets on startup, but I need to make sure that all of my exec()'ed processes are terminated when the server is shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to receive notifications about impending shutdown of a web application. You'll need to provide an implementation for the [`contextDestroyed`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextDestroyed%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) method, where you can terminate your processes.

You can also use the `ServletContextListener` to perform any startup operations, via it's [`contextInitialized`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) method.